# Entity Framework: List of Ids for many to many relation

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a method which is getting a List of Entity-IDs to be assigned to a many to many relation.

What is the best practise in this case to add the relation between EntityA and EntityB? Do I load each element of list B and add it to A or can I attach it without loading the entites?

```
public void AddToNewA(string name, List<int> listOfBIds)
{
   var a = new EntityA();
   a.Name = name;

   ...
}
public class EntityA{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<EntityB> EntityBList {get; set;}
}

publc class EntityB{
   public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

Furthermore what would be the approach if I would use a repository?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Is this about relations between existing entities, or could it also create new `EntityB`s?

Comment: What do you mean by " attach it without loading the entities"?  You mean just load the list of IDs bit not the rest of the data for B?

Comment: EntityA will be created and EntityB is already in the DB. Similar to a form (EntityA) where u can select multiple categories (EntityB) for your form.

Comment: I thought that a context.Attach would load the entity from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and even recommended to establish the connections between `EntityA` and `EntityB` without loading the latter from the database. You do this by creating *stub entities* for `EntityB` and attaching them as `Unchanged` to the context:

```
public void AddToNewA(string name, List<int> listOfBIds)
{
    var a = new EntityA();
    a.Name = name;
    foreach(int id in listOfBIds)
    {
        var b = new EntityB { ID = id };
        context.Entry(b).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
        a.EntityBs.Add(b);
    }
    context.EntityAs.Add(a);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hey Gert, thanks for ur solution! I could also use Attach instead of Add, right? In both cases I could set the State to unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Gert! Maybe I miss explained it a bit. I have a exisiting EntityB thats why u suggested me to use the methode Add and state change, right? But in this case I could use Attach, because it already sets the State to Unchaged after attaching the object to the  context. Is there any reason to not use Attach?